# What folder should I install Chrome in?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, google-chrome, directory

I just installed Chrome with [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line) on ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

But I installed it in my home folder. I'm quite new to Ubuntu and not sure where I'm meant to install it? When I run the 'ls' command in my home folder I see the google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb in red.

Can I move it or do I have to delete and reinstall it somewhere else?

(How would I delete it?)

Comment: @user68186 You might actually want to post that as an answer. It seems to me your comment is a much clearer answer to this question than either [the current answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/509779/22949) or [the answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/506791/22949). (In particular, I'm not sure the answer there is really correct, or would be if posted here--the reason `dpkg` doesn't install the software in the directory where it is run is not, *per se*, because it is run as root, as implied in that answer.) The question here is narrower and I think your comment answers it perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @EliahKagan I have deleted the comment and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Used up software Linux Downloads folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506786/used-up-software-linux-downloads-folder) for a similar question.

DEB is just a container. the `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb` command opened it and extracted the files needed and put them in their right places.

So you have nothing to worry about. Delete the deb file. When you install Chrome this way, it gets installed in the right place and from now on Ubuntu will take care of updating Chrome.

You could have opened the "File" icon on Launcher (the left panel on your desktop, assuming you are using Unity) and double clicked on the deb file. It would have opened **Ubuntu Software Center** and you would see an **Install** button there. Installing a deb file in either of these two ways (command `sudo dpkg..` or the GUI Software Center) always installs the software in their correct places. It is best not to mess with it and try to install the software in a different folder.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Kriss, you can simply download the 64bit .deb from Google's [site](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/?platform=linux) and double click it to open it in the Ubuntu Software Center. From there you can install it, uninstall it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

this tells Ubuntu to install the `.dpkg` file on your PC. If you're coming from Windows, consider that file as an MSI installer file. You can easily delete it

Comment: what do I run to delete it?

Comment: In your home folder do `rm google-chrome*.deb`

Comment: Chrome still works after I deleted it. So it is installed in another folder? When I search for google it seems like google has a file in every folder?

Comment: Oh..you want to delete chrome installation.. Then do `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome`

Comment: not at all. I just thought I installed it in my home folder. But it seems like I didn't. Do you know where it is? If I want to remove it can I run 'sudo apt-get remove google-chrome' from anywhere?

Comment: Yes..from anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16346/discussion-between-alexgreg-and-kriss).